# How to go back to Windows 10 after installing two major versions of Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

How do I do this? My audio drivers won't work unless Secure Boot is disabled. Right now I have no way back to Windows 10 because it was replaced with the previous Windows 11 build.

Comment: You recover it from the backup you made before using experimental beta software… or you save what you can onto a spare drive then wipe it & start over from https://www.microsoft.com/eb-gb/software-download/windows10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I uninstall Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1677870/how-do-i-uninstall-windows-11)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I do this?

What you want is impossible.  **You are only able to uninstall the most recent upgrade.**  This capability also only exists for 10 days since you performed the upgrade.  If the option to rollback your installation, results in you still being on an Insider Preview build of Windows 11, then your only option is to perform a clean install of Windows 10.

> Right now I have no way back to Windows 10 because it was replaced with the previous Windows 11 build.

In order to revert back to Windows 10 your only solution to your problem, is to download a current Windows 10 ISO, and revert back to Windows 10 by performing a clean install.  The only other option would be to wait until updated device drivers are released that support Windows 11.

Since you are running Windows 11 Insider Preview, having to disable Secure Boot, should not prevent the use of your machine.

Comment: You should backup any vital files before you revert back to Windows 10.

Comment: tbh, they should have been backed up before the upgrade - what happens if, for instance, the mailbox structure has changed [this often happens with macOS upgrades] If that happened copying the new mailbox back to Win10 wouldn't work.

Comment: @Tetsujin - What mailbox?

Comment: The one inside your emailer, whatever the system default is. I'm just using it as an example, because it bites people every year when macOS releases the beta & people want to revert. Basically, any structure that has changed between 10 & 11 that can't be reverted by copying that now updated structure back to Win10. Often people only discover which these are once they try… & fail.

Comment: @Tetsujin I readily admit that I don't go anywhere near macOS machines, but I never really encounter an end-user who does something with their Windows 10 mailbox.  They are either utilizing the Outlook desktop application or a web GUI.  As a result, I simply have them backup both their Public and Personal folders:  Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Music, Pictures, and Videos.  Never had anything that was "lost" during that process.

Comment: It could potentially happen with any system structure - the 'famous' one on Mac just happens to be the mbox structure, which gets 'versioned' - now up to v8 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm6nV.png - very old boxes used to survive for various reasons, though contain very little data, it mainly gets migrated to the new version. You cannot copy [or even convert] back to an older OS, it simply fails. This isn't the only structure, it's merely the most 'famous' one. Potentially, when going through a major OS update **anything** might do this; you won't know until you try to copy back to the older OS.

Comment: @Run5k - I have to admit I don't use Windows much - but I do run daily backups of the one machine I do have & I also have a complete restorable clone of it I can return to in 30 mins if I lose a boot drive etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Most users keep mail on the server, it takes a lot of effort, to actually download emails using the Mail UWP application on Windows 10.  I can't speak of anything about Windows 11 at this time, however, I would imagine it's running the same version.  I was speaking more of personal files instead of application data like for Mail (which the author made no mention of at all).

Comment: IMAP would have to resync… however long it took. POP would be lost forever. The author made absolutely no provision for a return to the current mainstream system… maybe next time.