# How do I uninstall Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

A couple of months ago I installed Windows 11 on my Windows 10 computer but now I want to turn it back to Windows 11. I looked at a couple of tutorials online and they said to use the go back option in settings but I deleted the `Windows.old` folders a while ago. The other ones said to download an external software but they also used the `Windows.old` folder so how do I turn it back to Windows 10 without `Windows.old` folder or resetting my computer?

How do I backup all the files and folders and then install Windows 10 and put all the files and folders back?

Comment: You did make a complete, restorable backup of your computer before testing a beta release, didn't you? [I'm assuming the answer is 'no' but you can see where I'm going with this, can't you?] **Rule #1** never test beta software or OSes on mission-critical devices.

Comment: If you cannot roll back (Settings, Update), then you have to do a fresh install of Windows 10. That has been made clear in the Windows Insider program.

Comment: Without a windows.old folder, your only choice is a fresh install of windows 10. That means, download the windows 10 usb stick creator, boot from it and install windows 10, removing all files in the process. So make proper backups.

Comment: Re your edit: Documents you copy off to another drive, apps you reinstall afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Operating systems are not "uninstalled".

As you've already removed the built in "roll back" functionality by deleting the Windows.old folder, the correct way to return to Windows 10 is to complete a fresh install of Windows 10 on the computer, removing Windows 11 in the process.